# Combine csv values and output to csv

Tags: python, list, csv, slice

I'm trying to read a csv file and combine the duplicate values then output the values into a csv again.

- Iterate through each line in the text file. The first line contains headers, so should be skipped.
- Separate the three values found in each line. Each line contains the product name, quantity sold, and unit price (the price of a single product), separated by a tab character.
- Keep a running total for the quantity sold of each product; for example, the total quantity sold for ‘product b’ is 12.
- Keep a record of the unit price of each product.
- Write the result to the sales-report.csv; the summary should include the name of each product, the sales volume (total quantity sold), and the sales revenue (total quantity sold * by the product price).

What I intend.

Input Data:

```
product name,quantity,unit price
product c,2,22.5
product a,1,10
product b,5,19.7
product a,3,10
product f,1,45.9
product d,4,34.5
product e,1,9.99
product c,3,22.5
product d,2,34.5
product e,4,9.99
product f,5,45.9
product b,7,19.7
```

Output Data:

```
product name,sales volume,sales revenue
product c,5,112.5
product a,4,40
product b,12,236.4
product f,6,275.4
product d,6,207
product e,5,49.95
```

This is what I have so far, I've looked around and it isn't entirely clear how I'm supposed to perform list comprehension and combine values.
When I looked for an answer, it was mostly more complicated than it probably needs to be, it is relatively simple...

```
    record = []
    with open("items.csv", "r") as f:
        next(f)
        for values in f:
            split = values.rstrip().split(',')
            record.append(split)
        print(record)
```

Comment: "record the unit price" ... can it be different for different rows with the same product? How would you record the price if so?

Comment: I believe I meant quantity * unit price = sales revenue

Comment: Yeah, I think I misread the requirements. No unit price in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` is the way to go with the problem. If you don't already use it, it aggregates operations across entire tables so you don't have to iterate yourself. Notice that entire columns can be multiplied in a single step. `groupby` will group the dataframe by each product and then its easy to sum.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("f.csv")
df["sales revenue"] = df["quantity"] * df["unit price"]
del df["unit price"]
outdf = df.groupby("product name").sum()
outdf.rename(columns={"quantity": "sales volume"})
outdf.to_csv("f-out.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the one that worked best. I was fiddling around reading the documentation for pandas but this explains my question precisely.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file')
```

Then calculate `sales revenue`, `groupby` and `sum`

`df = df.assign(sales_revenue=lambda x: x['quantity'] * x['unit price']).groupby('product name').sum().reset_index()`

```
  product name  quantity  sales_revenue
0    product a         4       20.00
1    product b        12       39.40
2    product c         5       45.00
3    product d         6       69.00
4    product e         5       19.98
5    product f         6       91.80
```

You can save the result to a csv file

`df.to_csv('new_file_name.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Wow thanks, that is so much simpler than what I was attempting. I'll look into using pandas more often for this kind of task.